# Glass bottle thickness ratings

Tags: equipment, storage, glass

I notice that the popular Bormioli Rocco stoppered glass bottles have numbers on the bottom. Some higher quality ones I have are numbered "18" and some more recently bought ones have the number "14". Does anyone know what these numbers mean?

Comment: Usually such numbers just identify which mold the glass was shaped in.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I doubt that because the mold for the bottom of the bottle is different than the mold used for the sides of the bottle.

Answer (score 3):

I did some some more research and Ecnerwal is right, it is a mold identification number.

Each manufacturer numbers their molds kind of like a baseball team has unique numbers for each player. This number is placed in the center of the bottom of the bottle.